# ASP.NET MVC project Automaic route to a random location

Tags: asp.net, redirect, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I got an MVC project working in `IISExpress`. But when hosted in Azure app service and local host's IIS, I got 302 redirect from http://localhost//facebookapp/start to http://localhost/(S(gf3a4leuiyjafjltxdjabhae))/facebookapp/start, then get 404.

I also reported this [here](https://github.com/idseefeld/FacebookFanpageApp/issues/1)

I realize this must be a router problem, but I have no clue how to trace it down.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the application I used the sample used localhost/facebookApp as the virtual directory, which certainly won't work if i blindly published to azure and IIS host.